# How can I remove parts of a string and None values from an item in from list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to remove all the '/api/1/employees/' and /api/1/seats/ from the python list of dictionaries. What is the easiest way to do so. My list of dictionaries are looking like this at the moment -`dict1 = [{'to_seat_url': '/api/1/seats/19014', 'id': 5051, 'employee_url': '/api/1/employees/4027'}, {'to_seat_url': '/api/1/seats/19013', 'id': 5052, 'employee_url': '/api/1/employees/4048'}, {'to_seat_url': '/api/1/seats/19012', 'id': 5053, 'employee_url': '/api/1/employees/4117'}, {'to_seat_url': None, 'id': 5054, 'employee_url': '/api/1/employees/15027'}]`

excepting below result:

`new_dict = [{'to_seat_url': '19014', 'id': 5051, 'employee_url': '4027'}, {'to_seat_url': '19013', 'id': 5052, 'employee_url': '4048'}, {'to_seat_url': '19012', 'id': 5053, 'employee_url': '4117'}, {'to_seat_url': '', 'id': 5054, 'employee_url': '15027'}]`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want last part of the URLs:

```py
new_dict = [
    {k: v.split("/")[-1] if k != "id" else v for k, v in d.items()}
    for d in dict1
]
print(new_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"to_seat_url": "19014", "id": 5051, "employee_url": "4027"},
    {"to_seat_url": "19013", "id": 5052, "employee_url": "4048"},
    {"to_seat_url": "19012", "id": 5053, "employee_url": "4117"},
    {"to_seat_url": "9765", "id": 5054, "employee_url": "15027"},
]
```

---

EDIT: To filter-out `None` values:

```py
new_dict = [
    {k: v.split("/")[-1] if k != "id" else v for k, v in d.items()}
    for d in dict1
    if not d is None
]
print(new_dict)
```

---

EDIT 2: If some values are `None`:

```py
new_dict = [
    {
        k: ("" if v is None else v.split("/")[-1]) if k != "id" else v
        for k, v in d.items()
    }
    for d in dict1
    if not d is None
]
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thank for the reply. I am having None values in my dictionary and I am getting 'AttributeError : 'Nonetype ' object has no attribute split'.

Comment: Hello Andrej, still I am getting same error with new code.

Comment: @Ashu Please edit your question and put sample input that causes an error and expected output.

Comment: Hello Andrey, I have updated sample question and sample inputs. Thanks